# Solving multivariable polynomial divisions

Tags: polynomials

*For reference my teacher has not gone through the subject as of yet, although we have already covered normal polynomial divisions. I am doing old exam sets, and there is one problem that is a multivariable polynomial division. The curriculum slightly changes from year to year, therefore i am not sure if this problem still applies to our course. I have yet to asked my teacher. I just wanted to have that cleared out before some of you start bashing me for asking what might seem to like  simple question for those who are already proficient at long divisions*

The expression is as follows.

$$\frac{(x^3-2ax^2+x)}{x-a}$$

The answer i get is $$(x^2-ax-a^2+1+\frac{a-a^2}{x-a})$$i must have messed up somewhere along the solving.

Here is my worked examples, using [image: long polynomial division], and [image: synthetic division.]

Comment: The numerator of the fraction is $a-a^3$.

Comment: @hardmath oh, i think i understand now. I've watched a couple of videos on that and i think you're referring to what the woman in this video is doing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EpU7TeIUC8

Comment: Dividing by $x-a$ is a bit of a special case, where we can use *synthetic division* as a shortcut.  In effect we find the remainder when dividing a polynomial by $x-a$ agrees with *evaluating* the polynomial at $x=a$.

Comment: @hardmath i've tried synthetic division doing the technique where you divide by something that is $(x+1)$, or $(x+4)$, substituting the number, for $a$, yet i dont know how to subtract when a variable, and still multiply it. Could you show me a worked example, ill update to include mine.

Comment: @hardmath could you see my worked example, i've added a photo. The synthetic division that i tried is right under my long polynomial division picture.

Comment: The synthetic division approach uses the coefficients of powers of $x$, so you should write them as $+1\;\;-2a\;\;+1\;\;0$, not forgetting the zero constant term of the dividend.

Comment: At your first summation $-2ax^2+ax^2=\color{red}-ax^2$